# mac-os :Not able to run protractor test in firefox chrome its s working fine

Tags: javascript, macos, jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using latest version of protractor and jasmine.My code is woking in chrome but in firefox its giving error.

Im using MAC-OS 
I am still learning so please give detailed answers.

Attached the screenshot.[image: config file and error]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably one or more geckodriver(s) still running in the background. You may try to kill -9 {geckodriver's PID}. Then run webdriver-manager update. It would work.